# Is there a better way to make a function silent on need?

Tags: python

I got a piece of code I'm not pleased with; Does anyone would have a better idea?

```
def myFunc(verbose=True):
    if not verbose:
        print = functools.partial(globals()['print'], file=open(os.devnull, 'w'))
    else:
        # Required, othewise I got the error 'local print variable was referenced before being declared' a few lines below…
        print = globals()['print']

    # Bunch of code with tons of print calls […]
```

I also tried the classical `sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, 'w')` but it can't work with my code because my print function is defined as such at the beginning of the code:

```
print = functools.partial(print, file=codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stdout.buffer)) # Make sure the output is in utf-8
```

But I'm not really fan about having to use globals twice.

Comment: It might be worth having a look at the logging facilities offered by Python.

Comment: @Josay Are you talking about the `logging` module? I shall have a look. Last time I tried I couldn't make it work with `cgitb` but I'm not using `cgitb` here so may be it could work. I would still prefer to have a solution which would always work.

Comment: @Josay Would it also mean that I would have to change my code anyway? (I mean replacing every print in my function or could I just put something on top just like I did here (I thought about implementing this as a decorator))

Comment: @JeromeJ: why are you clobbering a global function? that looks like a no-no, can't you name `log` or something?

Comment: @tokland The one at the beginning seems legit to me, everything else is only local (I think I could/should use `locals()` instead of `globals()`). About `log` maybe I could do something like `print = someKindOfLogModified`? (I don't want to rewrite the code of the functions, some aren't mine) But then, if I use `log`, some old probs will come back in some of my other codes (that's why I stopped using `log`, I couldn't make it work everywhere)

Comment: @JeromeJ: fair enough, it's a local clobbering, it's acceptable. If you are going to do this more than once, by all means, abstract it: `print = get_my_print(verbose)`. Btw, the error you get is normal, Python sees `print =` in the first branch so it decides that it's a local variable in this scope.

Comment: @tokland Isn't this a valid use case for the `global` keyword? (By the way, in a Unix world, deciding where the output goes is not decided in the code, except to separate standard output and standard error.)

Comment: Also, deciding on the output encoding is decided using the locale in Python, explicitely encoding everything in UTF-8 is asking for trouble IMHO, and is probably not the best place to fix a problem you're having.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on what you are looking to do.  For localized 'quiet' code, I use this:

```
class NoStdStreams(object):
    def __init__(self,stdout = None, stderr = None):
        self.devnull = open(os.devnull,'w')
        self._stdout = stdout or self.devnull or sys.stdout
        self._stderr = stderr or self.devnull or sys.stderr

    def __enter__(self):
        self.old_stdout, self.old_stderr = sys.stdout, sys.stderr
        self.old_stdout.flush(); self.old_stderr.flush()
        sys.stdout, sys.stderr = self._stdout, self._stderr

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self._stdout.flush(); self._stderr.flush()
        sys.stdout = self.old_stdout
        sys.stderr = self.old_stderr
        self.devnull.close()
```

then it is as easy as:

```
with NoStdStreams():
   print('you will never see this')
```

You could easily adapt it to:

```
with NoStdStreams(verbose):
    print('you may see this')
```

Comment: I like your idea but I gotta modify my code (and yours) if I want to use it (because of my way of overwriting `print` so that it doesn't even call `sys.stdout`)